# If $\lim_{n \to ∞} z_n=L_1$ then $\lim_{n \to ∞} \overline{z_n}=\overline{L_1}$ for $z_n \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-verification

I tried proving that if  $\lim_{n \to  ∞} z_n=L_1$ then $\lim_{n \to  ∞} \overline{z_n}=\overline{L_1}$ for $z_n \in \mathbb{C}$. This is my attemt.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such than $|z_n-L_1|<\epsilon$ for each $n>N$.

Now let $n>N$. 
$|z_n-L_1|<\epsilon$ implies that $\overline{|z_n-L_1|}<\epsilon$.

Thus $|\overline{z_n}-\overline{L_1}|<\epsilon$.

I am not at all sure of this proof. Hope someone can assist me. Thanks

Comment: The proof seems correct.

Comment: It is better to remark that $|\overline{z_n}-\overline{L_1}| = |z_n-L_1|$, since $|z|=|\overline{z}|$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$.